# Is there anyway we can authenticate to dev.azure.com using username and password and create and update bugs (C# Asp.net)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops
but there is a problem, it only uses **personal access token** to authenticate the user.

But in my case, I want the user to enter mail id and password, and then the authentication process should continue.

Thereafter, user can create or update bugs in the VSO or TFS using C# Asp.net

Comment: what's wrong with the personal access token approach? It only takes a moment for each user to create one

Comment: @ADyson For multi user, it is not possible.

Comment: if the user enters their ID then you can use the rest API in the background to get the access token (if your app authenticates to the API with suitable privileges). So it's not impossible, it's just a bit of extra work. But the solution below is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to connect with the following code (an empty `VssClientCredentials()`):

```
vssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl), new VssClientCredentials());
```

It's prompt for credentials:

[image]